# Not able to run the gaussian7x7 example of hexagon dsp

Tags: hexagon-dsp

I am trying to run the gaussian7x7 example of hexagon sdk. I am getting following errors:

```
map_object.c:521:0x9096:uimg not supported

map_object.c:521:0xa0a1:uimg not supported

symbol.c:336:0xc0e5:__cxa_finalize weak ref not found,return _rtld_sym_zero@_rtld_objmain

rtld.c:1026:0xc0e5:VA 0xFFB00000 outside ELF segment

symbol.c:336:0xc0e5:__cxa_finalize weak ref not found, return _rtld_sym_zero@_rtld_objmain

rtld.c:1026:0xc0e5:VA 0xFFB00000 outside ELF segment
```

I am unable to figure out what could be the possible errors?
Also the code gives error code as -1. Can somebody point me to the right direction in this regard

Comment: Which SDK version is this?

Comment: I am using the latest SDK i.e 3.3.3 have tried with older version too but i get the same error. I have tried running other examples like downscaleby2 and conv3x3 they work fine but gaussian example is not running